# Extracting certain data from an INI file

Tags: c#, string, ini

I have an INI file which has data   like this.

[username] xxxxxxxxxx

[password] xxxxxxxxxx

Now i want to extract both username and password and store them separately into a string.
I tried many things, but was not able to achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your example contained no <> at all...

Comment: Actually anything typed in between <> is not being displayed. I guess it acts as an escape character. So i removed it

Comment: @Sinatr, I'm already able to read data from an INI file!!!

Comment: Then how are we supposed to know what the contents are and how you should retrieve what you need? Show us EXACTLY what it looks like.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne, any help now!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the file format is not that of an INI file